# SwiftUI ScrollViewReader's scrollTo causing a memory leak

Tags: swift, swiftui, memory-leaks

I am getting a memory leak from the code bellow:

```swift
struct FeedTabs: View {
  let titles: [String]
  @Binding var selected: Int
  @Namespace var namespace

  var body: some View {
      ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
          HStack {
            ForEach(Array(titles.enumerated()),
                    id: \.element) { index, title in
              TabItem(title: title,
                      tag: index,
                      selected: $selected,
                      namespace: namespace).id(index)
            }
          }
          .animation(.spring(response: 0.3, dampingFraction: 0.6),
                     value: selected)
        }
        .onChange(of: selected, perform: { index in
          withAnimation {
            scrollProxy.scrollTo(index) // LEAK HERE
          }
        })
      }
  }
}
```

I used Instruments, and it tells me that the leak is caused by the closure scrollProxy.scrollTo(index), the leak goes away if I remove the latter.

I couldn't use weak/unowned on self/scrollProxy because they are structs.

[Instruments Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEBoB.png)

[Stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDELO.png)

Comment: Can you explain in brief as did not getting your question

Comment: @QaziAmmar I am getting a memory leak in the code above, Xcode's Leak detection tool (Instruments) tells me that the leak is happening in the line "scrollProxy.scrollTo(index)" (inside the withAnimation closure). usually, memory leaks are caused by retain cycles, so adding a [weak someVar] on the closer usually fixes the leak, but in this case, the variables used in the corresponding closer are just structs, which you can't use weak or unowned with.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Have tried numerous work arounds with no luck. I will file a bug with Apple and post any update.